# What is a Unit Test?

Tags: unit-tests

When addressing an answer that had a flawed understanding of what a Unit Test is, I wanted to link to this question. But I found it didn't exist yet.

What is a Unit Test? And for completeness: what makes it different from a Functional Test or an Integration Test, or an Automated Test?

Comment: I can give you a secret weapon: google search: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=unit+test

Comment: @PeterMasiar You misunderstand. I know what a Unit Test is, better than most people do. But I still can't link to a answer on this site that says what it is.

Comment: My ESP ball is in repair shop and you did not linked to any of your own research so I have no idea how much you already know and where to start explaining

Comment: @PeterMasiar It doesn't matter how much I know, but you can either write a helpful answer for a general audience, or you can move on to another question. I consider self-answering questions without giving others a chance first to be bad form.

Comment: Sharing knowledge is good idea and is promoted, but asking questions which can be directly found via simple search is not a good practice for this site. Anyone can share his/her knowledge and ask such questions, whose answer can be useful for others. But asking questions like this will not be beneficial for any one or everyone will start asking What is unit testing, What is beta, alpha, functional, non-functional testing etc. Please understand the intent of this site.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904096/whats-the-difference-between-unit-functional-acceptance-and-integration-test

Comment: @Peter as I said, please state clearly your intention. If you plan to self-answer to enlighten others, say so. How we are supposed to guess it? Volume of the noise and low quality questions is through the roof recently.

Comment: I'm afraid 7 years this would have gotten you hundreds of upvotes on SO itself. 5 years ago it would have gotten you upvotes and a close. However, this is now and I expect you'll just get deleted. Sorry.

Comment: @Bookeater I was under the assumption this site was supposed to be a knowledge repository. Obviously you disagree, but that's a question for meta.

Comment: Peter, I do not disagree, actually I agree with you intention. I'm just pointing out the site no longer works that way. You already got a second down-vote and a third close-vote, sadly.

Comment: @Bookeater Ok, seems I jumped to conclusions, sorry about that. Anyway, it's funny how some comments complain the answer is easy to google, and close reason is that the question is too broad to be answered.

Comment: For contrast, look here (dated 2009): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-last-commits-in-git

Answer (score 1):

A [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904096/whats-the-difference-between-unit-functional-acceptance-and-integration-test) from stackoverflow:

> Depending on where you look, you'll get slightly different answers.
>   I've read about the subject a lot, and here's my distillation; again,
>   these are slightly wooly and others may disagree.
>
> **Unit Tests**
>
> Tests the smallest unit of functionality, typically a method/function
>   (e.g. given a class with a particular state, calling x method on the
>   class should cause y to happen). Unit tests should be focussed on one
>   particular feature (e.g., calling the pop method when the stack is
>   empty should throw an InvalidOperationException). Everything it
>   touches should be done in memory; this means that the test code and
>   the code under test shouldn't:
>
> - Call out into (non-trivial) collaborators
> - Access the network
> - Hit a database
> - Use the file system
>     Spin up a thread
>     etc.
>
> Any kind of dependency that is slow / hard to understand / initialise
>   / manipulate should be stubbed/mocked/whatevered using the appropriate
>   techniques so you can focus on what the unit of code is doing, not
>   what its dependencies do.
>
> In short, unit tests are as simple as possible, easy to debug,
>   reliable (due to reduced external factors), fast to execute and help
>   to prove that the smallest building blocks of your program function as
>   intended before they're put together. The caveat is that, although you
>   can prove they work perfectly in isolation, the units of code may blow
>   up when combined which brings us to ...
>
> **Integration Tests**
>
> Integration tests build on unit tests by combining the units of code
>   and testing that the resulting combination functions correctly. This
>   can be either the innards of one system, or combining multiple systems
>   together to do something useful. Also, another thing that
>   differentiates integration tests from unit tests is the environment.
>   Integration tests can and will use threads, access the database or do
>   whatever is required to ensure that all of the code and the different
>   environment changes will work correctly.
>
> If you've built some serialization code and unit tested its innards
>   without touching the disk, how do you know that it'll work when you
>   are loading and saving to disk? Maybe you forgot to flush and dispose
>   filestreams. Maybe your file permissions are incorrect and you've
>   tested the innards using in memory streams. The only way to find out
>   for sure is to test it 'for real' using an environment that is closest
>   to production.
>
> The main advantage is that they will find bugs that unit tests can't
>   such as wiring bugs (e.g. an instance of class A unexpectedly receives
>   a null instance of B) and environment bugs (it runs fine on my
>   single-CPU machine, but my colleague's 4 core machine can't pass the
>   tests). The main disadvantage is that integration tests touch more
>   code, are less reliable, failures are harder to diagnose and the tests
>   are harder to maintain.
>
> Also, integration tests don't necessarily prove that a complete
>   feature works. The user may not care about the internal details of my
>   programs, but I do!
>
> **Functional Tests**
>
> Functional tests check a particular feature for correctness by
>   comparing the results for a given input against the specification.
>   Functional tests don't concern themselves with intermediate results or
>   side-effects, just the result (they don't care that after doing x,
>   object y has state z). They are written to test part of the
>   specification such as, "calling function Square(x) with the argument
>   of 2 returns 4".
>
> **Acceptance Tests**
>
> Acceptance testing seems to be split into two types:
>
> Standard acceptance testing involves performing tests on the full
>   system (e.g. using your web page via a web browser) to see whether the
>   application's functionality satisfies the specification. E.g.
>   "clicking a zoom icon should enlarge the document view by 25%." There
>   is no real continuum of results, just a pass or fail outcome.
>
> The advantage is that the tests are described in plain English and
>   ensures the software, as a whole, is feature complete. The
>   disadvantage is that you've moved another level up the testing
>   pyramid. Acceptance tests touch mountains of code, so tracking down a
>   failure can be tricky.
>
> Also, in agile software development, user acceptance testing involves
>   creating tests to mirror the user stories created by/for the
>   software's customer during development. If the tests pass, it means
>   the software should meet the customer's requirements and the stories
>   can be considered complete. An acceptance test suite is basically an
>   executable specification written in a domain specific language that
>   describes the tests in the language used by the users of the system.
>
> **Conclusion**
>
> They're all complementary. Sometimes it's advantageous to focus on one
>   type or to eschew them entirely. The main difference for me is that
>   some of the tests look at things from a programmer's perspective,
>   whereas others use a customer/end user focus.

Comment: Not sure how beneficial is answer solely consisting of a long quote of some other answer from sister website. Losing all the context and comments. But of course you have every right to write it :-)